# $this->load does not work on Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I get error if I use  with $this->load->view(... but it works if I use echo view(...
Error is : Call to a member function view() on null

I get same error if I try to load a model with $this->load->model(...

Comment: CI 4.x is not CI 3.x and not compatible at all, as it is a complete re-write. there are great online docs, check [Views in CI 4.x](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/views.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output directly to browser with   `echo view('')`
If you want to get a view and for example send though ajax use `return view('')`

This is new in CI4, there is not more `$this->load->view('')`

Note that if the last line of the execution is `return view('')` it still is passes to the browser.

All this applies to models and libraries. Now its more OO rather than having a super object.

For example if you have a model located under App/Models, in the controller or where you want to load it include the namespace i.e. `use App\Models\MyModel` at the beginning and then in method you want to use just create a new class i.e.

```
$myModel = new MyModel();
```

If you want an instance of a library helper for example the db in you model do this constructor for your model:

```
protected mixed $db;
public function __construct(ConnectionInterface &$db)
{
    $this->db = &$db;
}
```

In the base controller `initController` method put

`$this->db = \Config\Database::connect();`

Now when you create an instance of the model from a controller which extends BaseController pass the db instance:

```
$myModel = new MyModel($this->db);
```

Note that `$this` in CI4 does not refere to the superobject but to the controller instance i.e. whatever you load in `initController` can be found in `$this`. There are several helpers and libraries that in CI4 now are loaded by default such as `$this->request->getPost('')`

Please read the documentation [CI4 Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html) especially if you are used to CI3