# My Question How i put my code to Models and Controler Codeigniter4

Tags: codeigniter-4

i make navbar dinamic from my table i want to take my code view to models and controler but i stuck in there i just can created in my view

My code

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <?php
                        $db = \Config\Database::connect();
                        $builder = $db->table('navbar');
                        $navbar = $builder->where('parent_id', '0')->where('status', '1')->orderBy('id_nav', 'ASC')->get()->getResultArray();
                        ?>
                        <?php foreach ($navbar as $menu) : ?>
                            <?php
                            $db = \Config\Database::connect();
                            $builder = $db->table('navbar');
                            $subnav = $builder->where('parent_id', $menu['id_nav'])->where('status', '1')->orderBy('id_nav', 'ASC')->get()->getResultArray();
                            ?>

                            <?php if ($subnav != Null) : ?>
                                <?php foreach ($subnav as $nav) : ?>
                                    <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?= $menu['nav_name']; ?></a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown" style="border: 0px solid; background:#f8f9f9;">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><?= $nav['nav_name']; ?></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><?= $menu['nav_name']; ?> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">LOGIN</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success my-4 my-sm-0" type="submit">JOIN ME</button>
                        </a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

code

***My Question How i put my code to Models and Controler Codeigniter4***

Comment: wrong my grammer

Comment: you need to visit the documentation. very clear in there

Answer (score 1):

This might help you get started [How to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703511/this-load-does-not-work-on-codeigniter-4/67707518#67707518)

Read the documentation it explains everything now that it was updated.
Moreover it seems that you do not have any idea what an MVC pattern is since you are loading the db in the view. I might start from there. [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)